# Bash: pass multiline output of grep to another command that loops

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have the following command to grep the kafka topics

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181 | grep repartition
```

This give me a shell output with multiple topics

```
dev-ALPHA_CLUSTER-investment.ed.store.alpha_cluster-repartition
dev-CUSTOM_GROUP-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition
dev-CUSTOM_GROUP-investment.ed.store.custom_group-repartition
```

I need to provide these topics one by one to another command

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic TOPIC_NAME
```

where `TOPIC_NAME` is the topic(s) from the previous grep command. I was wondering if there is a way to combine them such that if the grep has some results (topics separated by newline) then the other command is executed in a loop with `TOPIC_NAME` being each topic returned by grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xargs`

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181 | grep repartition | xargs -i kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs -n1` for executing the one parameter at a time:

```
zookeeper="--zookeeper localhost:2181"
kafka-topics --list ${zookeeper} | grep repartition |
   xargs -n1 kafka-topics ${zookeeper} --alter --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181 | grep repartition | sed 's/^/kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic /g'
```

The sed-part of the command is prepending `kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --config cleanup.policy=compact --topic` (including the space at the end) to output of `kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181`. You can either redirect those commands to a file or redirect them to `bash` to run them directly.